# Instance not found SQL,WCF and IIS

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, rest, sql-server-2012

I know there are a lot of Questions like this, if there is one similar to mine I will appreciate a link for it.

I published my WCF on a `Windows Server 2012 R2`  Server and hosted my Service with IIS.

Both the Service and SQL works fine on there own the issue is when I try to call data from SQL through my Service I get this error.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The exception message is 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'. See server logs for more details.

Any Ideas on why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the server name in connection string

> else

Fix/Workaround/Solution:

```
Step 1) Make sure SQL SERVER is up and the instance you try to connect is running.
```

> `Step 2) Your system Firewall should not block SQL Server port.`

```
Step 3) Go to Computer Management >> Service and Application >> SQL Server 2012 Configuration >> Network Configuration
```

[HELP](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html)

[Help link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

Comment: add name="DbConnection" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Do I need to add that to My connection string on IIS or in my Service, Sorry still noob on this.

Comment: "Data Source=localhost"
instead of
"Data Source=MYSERVER\MyInstance"